# Why doesn't PhpWord recognize &?

Tags: phpword

I tried executing a paragraph that has '&'  but it fails to open and throws an error while opening but it works the other way round which is without '&'.Any help will be greatly appreciated?

Answer (score 0):

because Word documents are XML under the covers the `&` symbol is reserved. If you want to use it in text you will need to replace it with `&amp;`

eg:

```
$safe_text = str_replace("&",'&amp;', $unsafe_text);
$section->addText($safe_text);
```